# Stackdriver agen on GCE routing issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've been following the instructions for installing the stackdriver agent on a CentOS 7 VM.

This VM has access to internet: I can run a traceroute toward www.google.com or other public services without any issue.

```
[root@dbrocket sysconfig]# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.141.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from vl-in-f99.1e100.net (74.125.141.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=74.0 ms
64 bytes from vl-in-f99.1e100.net (74.125.141.99): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=73.0 ms
```

When I try to start the stackdriver agent it fails as follows:

```
Apr 03 02:42:55 dbrocket stackdriver-agent[25065]: Starting stackdriver-collectd: Unable to determine collectd endpoint!
Apr 03 02:42:55 dbrocket systemd[1]: stackdriver-agent.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 03 02:42:55 dbrocket systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop Stackdriver Agent.
```

Looking at the source, it looks like it fails to connect to the stackdriver gateway service, and indeed there is no way to reach it:

```
[root@dbrocket sysconfig]# traceroute -n collectd-gateway.google.stackdriver.com
traceroute to collectd-gateway.google.stackdriver.com (173.255.114.144), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  10.80.0.2  36.808 ms  36.733 ms  36.764 ms
2  * * *
3  * * *
4  * * *
5  * * *
6  * * *
```

These are API permission that this VM has:

```
[root@dbrocket sysconfig]# curl --silent -f -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud.useraccounts.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
```

I am going to build another VM with the additional `google-cloud-plaform` API authorization scope, but still this routing issue looks very weird. I have tried from various VMs with proper internet access and they all show the same behavior.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found my own answer, there was an offending default route configured in the firewall configuration for the main network, now the agent is working properly

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved by fixing firewall rules in the main network configuration